# Redefining fputc function when using arm-none-eabi toolchain

Tags: c, gcc, g++, stm32, redefinition

We have an `STM32` C/C++ project and we have redefined the weak `fputc(int, FILE *)` function in order to redirect `printf` output to some `UART` channel.

Up until now, we were building the project under **IAR** with the [**IAR compiler**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAR_Systems). The logging through `UART` was working fine.

We have now switched to the `arm-none-eabi toolchain` and are building the project with `g++`. But it looks like the redefinition of the `fputc` function is not linked anymore and so the `UART` logging is not working.

How can I force the use of the redefined function by `printf`?

Answer (score 4):

Just had the same problem converting project from Keil to Cube. Found this elegant [STM32 printf retarget to UART](https://gist.github.com/glegrain/ca92f631e578450a933c67ac3497b4df) solution on GitHub (and please forgive the copy-paste):

```
/*# 7- Retarget printf to UART (std library and toolchain dependent) #########*/

#if defined(__GNUC__)
int _write(int fd, char * ptr, int len)
{
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *) ptr, len, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  return len;
}
#elif defined (__ICCARM__)
#include "LowLevelIOInterface.h"
size_t __write(int handle, const unsigned char * buffer, size_t size)
{
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *) buffer, size, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  return size;
}
#elif defined (__CC_ARM)
int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)&ch, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    return ch;
}
#endif

// OR:

// Add syscalls.c with GCC

#ifdef __GNUC__
#define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int __io_putchar(int ch)
#else
#define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)
#endif /* __GNUC__ */

/**
  * @brief  Retargets the C library printf function to the USART.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE
{
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)&ch, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  return ch;
}
```

This may or may not work in your particular case, but you get the Idea...
In my case, I had to prepend function type with `extern "C"` :

```
extern "C" int _write(int fd, char * ptr, int len)
{
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *) ptr, len, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  return len;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `arm-none-eabi-` toolchain is using newlib, which lets you redefine `_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)` instead, all stdio output functions would then use that interface. `fd==1` would correspond to `stdout`, `fd==2` to `stderr`. You must provide a few more stub functions, like

```
void _exit(int) {
  while(1)
    ;
}
```

etc. Most of them are trivial, but `printf()` requires a working `_sbrk()` too, because it uses `malloc()` internally.

Comment: I have tried redefining `_write(int, const void*, size_t)` but it is not linked. Anything more I should do to make it work ? Also, where can I  get the list of all other functions that I should redefine ?

Comment: What do you mean by *not linked*? Does the linker fail with an error message (then copy it here), or is it silently ignored, and not showing up in the `.map` file? Are you indeed using `newlib` and the supplied headers or something else? What other library functions did you replace?

Comment: [The user-supplied functions are documented here](https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Syscalls), with trivial implementation examples. You don't have to actually implement all of them, only the ones that the linker can't resolve.

Comment: I've redefined only `_write`. Actually, it is in the .map but when I debug, I cannot set a breakpoint inside the function, that's why I was thinking it was ignored by the linker. Yes, I'm using newlib. I didn't replace any other library function.